# Generated random samples of dependent ratios

Tags: poisson-distribution, random-generation

The question is simple, however I am stuck:

I am trying to generate samples of ratios of "detections" vs "non-detections":

Say I counted 10 stars, and I could detect 8 stars. My detection ratio thus is 8/10.
Since this is a counting experiment, I would have naively assumed that both are Poisson variables and I can simply generate:

```
sample_classified = np.random.poisson(8, size=100)
sample_total      = np.random.poisson(10, size=100)

ratio = sample_classified/sample_total
```

this than can give me ratios that are greater than one, if the `sample_classified > sample_total`. That is however not logical since I can't have more classified stars as than there are in total.

The drawn samples should reflect that the ratio 8/10 is determined from an experiment, i.e. their histogram should peak at that value.

What is the correct PDF to sample from in that case?

Comment: You have to assume a true average detection probability, and make an assumption about whether the detection of each individual star is an independent Bernoulli trial.

Comment: This question might be more suited to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would do a sort of hierarchical model, like this:

1. First, choose the denominator via a Poisson distribution:

```
array_length = 100
sample_total = np.random.poisson(10, size=array_length)
```

2. Next, loop through `sample_total` and choose a binomially-distributed integer from $0$ to the total:

```
# Pre-allocate array for speed.
binomial_probability = 0.8
sample_classified = np.zeros(array_length, dtype=np.int64)
for i in range(array_length):
    limit = sample_total[i]
    sample_classified[i] = np.random.binomial(limit, binomial_probability)
```

This assumes a binomial distribution for the number of classified stars, once the Poisson total has been determined. Only you can tell us if that's a good assumption. But this code guarantees that, for each total, the number of classified stars will be less than or equal to the total.

Comment: Dear Adrian, I will specify my question in a second. However, this is not want I want to do. The number of detected stars (8) and the number of total star are expected values. So my samples should include that "knowledge".

Comment: Sure! If you say "expected values", then you are implying an underlying distribution - otherwise you can't compute an expected value. Which distribution does the detected stars come from?

Comment: I count them, thus I would have assumed that they too are Poisson distributed?

Comment: Not sure I follow you, there. I could just as easily count the numbers in a discrete uniform distribution such as I used above. The Poisson distribution is particularly good for predicting how many events will occur at a particular time, when in a small time interval, the probabilities are equal. So I could definitely see using Poisson for the sample totals. But here's the problem: you have a hard cutoff, as you've mentioned, that says you can't classify more stars than the total. The Poisson does not act like that, and so it is unsuitable for that distribution.

Comment: Here's perhaps another way of thinking about it: given a particular total of stars, how many of them would you expect to be able to classify or detect? I would say your main options are binomial, hypergeometric, or discrete uniform. jwimberly has hinted that perhaps binomial would be the right distribution. In that case, you would need to decide what the probability of detecting a single star is (your $p$ parameter).

Comment: If I have a given total amount of stars I would expect to have:
0.8=8/10
If I had 20 total stars, that expected ratio should still be 0.8. But I am wondering what the shape of that distribution is, since both numbers are "counted", i.e. poisson

Comment: You need to get our of your head the notion that "able to count" means Poisson. That just isn't true. What you're saying indicates binomial with $p=0.8.$ I will adjust my answer accordingly.